# List all of the files starting with sh, sr, se, th, tr or te

Tags: text-processing, files, regular-expression

How can I list all of the files starting with the sequence `sh`, `sr`, `se`, `th`, `tr` or `te` (either letter could be upper or lowercase).

Comment: homework? Have looked at how that might be done? E.g. do you know how one would look for files starting with just an s?

Comment: What have you tried? How did it not work as expected or intended?

Comment: ls  /[sh, sr, se, th, tr,te]* that's what I have tried but doesn't work

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add that information so it's all in one place. Make it easy for people to help you. (Remember to explain what "_doesn't work_" means - we can't see what you saw.)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you meant the *name* of the files and not their *contents* should start with any of those strings, you could have your shell do the filename generation and pass the list to `printf '%s\n'` or `ls -ld` for instance:

```
ls -ld [sStT][hHrReE]*
```

`[...]` is a shell glob operator supported by most shells (except `fish`) that matches any *single* character (or possibly *collating element* in some cases) in the specified set. So, here it's well suited for this specific set of strings. But for arbitrary sets of strings, you'd need to switch to a shell with more advanced globbing operators like zsh:

```
set -o extendedglob # needed for (#i) to set case insensitivity
ls -ld (#i)(foo|bar|[st][hre])*
```